# subprocess.run not executing commands when python called from php

Tags: python, php

I have this part of a php program:

```
$docx_filename = "/var/www/editeur/docx/".$file1
$command5 = "python3 conv_docx_pdf.py \"$docx_filename\"";
$output = shell_exec($command5);
```

The script conv_docx_pdf.py:

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys

def docx_to_pdf(input_file):
    # Get the file name without extension
    file_name, _ = os.path.splitext(input_file)
    
    # Construct the output file path with .pdf extension
    output_file = file_name + ".pdf"
    
    # Run unoconv to convert DOCX to PDF
    subprocess.run(["unoconv", "-f", "pdf", input_file])

    
    return output_file

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python script.py <input_file>")
        sys.exit(1)
    
    input_file = sys.argv[1]  # Get the input file from command-line argument
    output_file = docx_to_pdf(input_file)
    print("Output PDF:", output_file)
```

The command (`python3 conv_docx_pdf.py filename1.docx`) works fine when I execute it in ubuntu terminal. However, php is unable to execute it.

rights for folder docx:

> drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 26 12:58 docx

rights for file $file1

> -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 11738 Mar 26 11:45 status29024.docx

I have other python programs (that don't use subprocess) that are working fine when called from php.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?  "php is unable to execute it" could mean it couldn't find the binary, or there are permissions issues on the binary.   Please include the error message.  Take a look at the php.log file and check what it's complaining about.

Comment: So you're calling a Python script that calls unoconv? Why don't you call unoconv directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank you all for your help. I finally found the issue to be related to Unoconv and www-data permissions. I used the recommendations from [this](https://assen.xyz/unoconv-and-www-data-permissions-problem-solved-for-me/) site.

```
cd /var/www/
sudo mkdir .cache
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .cache/
sudo chmod -R 744 .cache/
sudo mkdir .config
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .config/ 
sudo chmod -R 744 .config/
```

Answer (score 0):

> The command (python3 conv_docx_pdf.py filename1.docx) works fine when I execute it in ubuntu terminal.

The command that is generated by the code you provided is not `python3 conv_docx_pdf.py filename1.docx` but `python3 conv_docx_pdf.py "filename1.docx"` (please note the extra quotes).

Try this code instead after adding a semicolon at the end of line 2:

```
$file1 = "filename1.docx";
$docx_filename = "/var/www/editeur/docx/" . $file1;
$command5 = "python3 conv_docx_pdf.py $docx_filename";

$output = shell_exec($command5);
```